# MEF 2 attribute-less importing

Tags: c#, mef

I'm working on an application using MEF 2. I wanted to try attribute-less way of designing plugins and now I'm trying to figure out why one of my objects does not seem to be satisfying its Import.
Below is sample code.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Registration;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MEF2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new RegistrationBuilder();
            builder.ForType<ExporterClass>().Export<ExporterClass>();
            builder.ForType<ImporterClass>().Export().ImportProperties(p => p.Name == "Exporter");
            var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), builder);
            CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
            ImporterClass t = new ImporterClass();
            container.ComposeParts(t);
            t.ShowWalkers();
        }
    }

    public class ExporterClass
    {
        public void Write()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test");
        }
    }

    public class ImporterClass : IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification
    {
        //[Import]
        private ExporterClass Exporter { get; set; }

        public void ShowWalkers()
        {
            if (Exporter != null)
                Exporter.Write();
        }
        public void OnImportsSatisfied()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification");
        }
    }
}
```

`OnInputSatisfied` event is fired but Exporter property is still null. If I uncomment `[Import]` attribute everything works.

What should I do to import without an attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can use [CompositionContainer.ComposeParts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.attributedmodelservices.composeparts.aspx) with MEF Conventions. I think it is for the attributed model only.

To make your example work replace:

```
ImporterClass t = new ImporterClass();        
container.ComposeParts(t);
```

with:

```
ImporterClass t = container.GetExportedValueOrDefault<ImporterClass>();
```

And change the `ImporterClass.Exporter` to `public`. `MEF Conventions` allow imports only on public properties.